# Creating a time-lapse effect image from multiple exposures

Tags: layers, blend-modes

I am trying to create a single image from multiple photographs taken with the continuous shooting mode on my camera.  The images are of a person jumping over a gap in some rocks.

What I would like to know is how to 'merge' these all together.  The images all have the same background as they were taken from the same place, I just want to have the time-lapse effect, where the image shows all the stages of the person jumping?  Does that make sense?

I know it's not the most advanced stuff, but I'm no designer! I just like playing around with my photies!  :D

Thanks in advance.

PS. I'd like to do it in Photoshop, if poss.

edit : here's the URL to a webpage showing an example of how I want my image to look.

Also, I've managed to 'sort of' get the effect I want, using the Blend Darken option on each layer, but certain parts of each photo are now not showing properly.  I'd like each image to still be nice and clear.

:)

Comment: I didn't see your url, but I get the idea I think.

Answer (score 2):

Load each image into a separate layer in PS.

[image: File - scripts - load into stack]

From here you just choose the main image, the one you want to use the background from.

Then just add a blurred mask to every other image and they should show nicely as a time-laps (hoping I understood your purpose). This is of course only one way to add a mask:

[image: Marking area]

Then add this as a mask to the layer:

[image: Mask added to layer]

Resulting (in this fantastic time-laps!):

[image: Time-laps]